# How to save as with VBA in current location

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently saving my excel file with this command:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="pleasework", FileFormat:=52
```

*But* when it saves it, it saves it in documents.

I want to save it in the current location of the macro (of the file, where it's activated).
Any advice? Changing it to:

```
Filename:="C:/pleasework"
```

Won't work...

**Thanks**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try

```
...
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\pleasework", FileFormat:=52
...
```

In addition you may first want to check whether `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` returns a valid path so in case your currently open file wasn't saved yet you won't try to save it to an invalid path.

Comment: Still saving in the same place - documents.. Any idea why?

Comment: Well I just tested it and it worked as far as I understand the question. Do you have a simple workbook with a macro within it or some kind of add-in?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I do have simple workbook with macro in it. But when I save it in your way, it still saves it in documents...

Comment: Sorry! Working just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Tell me, is this "Application." neccesary?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub Book_Path()

    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "pleasework", FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll try that shortly. Can you give me exmaple of ThisWorkbook.Path?